# Determine if $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$ is open closed or neither

Tags: general-topology

Determine if $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$ is open closed or neither.

I've been on this problem for a while now. As of right now I pretty confident its neither because I dont really see how it can be open or closed. I am having trouble showing that its neither, any help?

Comment: What definition of open/closed are you using? I just realized my answer assumes you are familiar with the axioms of a topological space.

Comment: opened: $S = S^{int}$ (S contains no boundary points) and closed: S contains its boundary @DanZimm

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the arbitrary union of open intervals is open?

Comment: @DanZimm yes I am

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Put $A_i = (i, i+1)$ then $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N} = (-\infty, 0) \cup \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i$

---

**Hint 2:** Check out the sequence $\{1+1/n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: For set $A$ to be open (in the usual topology on the reals), for each $x\in A$, you have to be able to find an open interval containing $x$ that stays completely in $A$.  For your set, given any noninteger $x$, can you find an open interval about $x$ that contains no integers?

Comment: no, but wouldn't that just show that it is not open?

Comment: ^That would show that the complement of $\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{N}$, if you need) in $\mathbb{R}$ is open.

Comment: sure, but how do I show that it is not closed as well?

Comment: If $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ were closed, its complement, $\mathbb{N}$, would be open. Can you show that it isn't?

Comment: @NickD. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is closed and since $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$ is the compliment of $\mathbb{N}$ wouldn't $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$ be open then?

Comment: Yes. You can also see that $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ is $(\infty,0)\cup(0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup(2,3)\cup\ldots$ so that it is a union of open sets.